# Firebase Android - будут ли приходить отчеты при установке из apk?

Tags: android, firebase

Создал приложение.Добавил Firebase. Переслал по почте apk, а инфо о крэшах не приходит. Так и должно быть?
в project:

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
```

добавил `google-service.json`
Ну и в console.firebase.google.com проект настроил.

Запустил в студии - все ок. Ошибки ловит, они появляются в отчетах, но при переносе apk на другое устройство - либо ошибки не отправляются либо приложение кэшается при запуске.

Comment: Firebase после нынешнего Google IO, стал очень широким понятием и продуктом с кучей фич. Уточните что и как вы добавили.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja уточнил